# HTML Not Auto Completing or Providing Options

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I think HTML Autocomplete is supposed to be built into VSCode, but when I type for example `<p>` and ctrl space there are no relevant html autocomplete options.  How do we get these?

I think another plugin may be overriding the built in intellisense.  How would I trouble shoot that?

Answer (score 1):

VS Code's built-in html intellisense only suggests tags when it looks like you are in tag (such after a `<` to open or close the tag)

[image]

When you are in a text context, such as inside the tag body, we will not suggest tags. However [Emmet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) is still enabled inside of tag bodies.

Comment: For me it's not suggesting anything relevant.  I think another plugin may be overriding VSCodes intellisense, but how do I troubleshoot that?

Answer (score 1):

1. But it only suggest closing tag if u want to read documentation then
   [read more about vs code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs)
2. If u inside the body tag u will not suggest tag because Emmet abbreviations is enabled [read Emmet abbreviation documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet)